# PHP: get webpage content that is delayed

Tags: curl, file-get-contents

I'm trying to download the content of a webpage for my work (the content is related to biological data). But when opened on a web browser, the webpage first indicates a message "loading ..." and only after displays its content.

Using the PHP function file_get_contents, the output file only contains the header, footer and the "loading ..." message, not the information I need (those that are delayed).

NB: I got the same result using curl in a terminal

Is there a way to pause file_get_contents so that the webpage could load before downloading the data ?

many thanks

Comment: It's likely that there's either a redirect happening, or an AJAX request triggering the data to be loaded. Open the Developer tools in your browser (if possible) to see what's actually being loaded, and then fetch that URL.

Comment: thanks ! I will try to identify them.